# Clean Code Book by Robert Cecil Martin

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, c#-6.0

I know this has been asked before but I did not fully understand the answer nor did I feel the question was exactly the same as this one.

In the book Clean Code Book by Robert Cecil Martin, He suggests with regards to methods you should...

- Prefer to not pass any parameters
- If you must pass paramters then pass only one.
- An only pass more than this under rare circumstances.

This has me confused...

So based on this which is correct?

this class...

```
 class FourNumberAdder
        {
            public int Num1 { get; }
            public int Num2 { get; }
            public int Num3 { get; }
            public int Num4 { get; }

            public FourNumberAdder(int n1, int n2,int n3,int n4 )
            {
                this.Num1 = n1;
                this.Num2 = n2;
                this.Num3 = n3;
                this.Num4 = n4;

            }

        }
```

with this...

```
FourNumberAdder FNA = new FourNumberAdder(1,2,3,4);
```

Or, This class...

```
class FourNumberAdder
    {
        public int Num1 { get; set; }
        public int Num2 { get; set; }
        public int Num3 { get; set; }
        public int Num4 { get; set; }



    }
```

with this...

```
public void go()
{
    FourNumberAdder FNA = new FourNumberAdder();
                    FNA.Num1 = 1;
                    FNA.Num2 = 2;
                    FNA.Num3 = 3;
                    FNA.Num4 = 4;
}
```

or these 2 classes...

```
class FourNumberAdder
    {
        public int Num1 { get; set; }
        public int Num2 { get; set; }
        public int Num3 { get; set; }
        public int Num4 { get; set; }

       public FourNumberAdder (FourNumbers fn)
        {
            this.Num1 = fn.Num1;
            this.Num2 = fn.Num2;
            this.Num3 = fn.Num3;
            this.Num4 = fn.Num4;


        }

    }




class FourNumbers
    {
        public int Num1 { get; set; }
        public int Num2 { get; set; }
        public int Num3 { get; set; }
        public int Num4 { get; set; }

    }
```

with this...

```
FourNumbers fn = new FourNumbers();

                fn.Num1 = 1;
                fn.Num2 = 2;
                fn.Num3 = 3;
                fn.Num4 = 4;

            FourNumberAdder FNA = new FourNumberAdder(fn);
```

or something else? Please note I thought the last option would be right as it 'bundles up' the 4 parameters in to a new class, but then you end up with the same problem with that class as you have to either pass all the parameters in individually or access them directly via there properties.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: I personally make an exception to that rule for constructor parameters that can't be split up into separate categories (if they could be subcategorised, the ctor params could be put into separate classes and passed as fewer parameters).

Comment: However, this question is not a good fit for this site because the answers are likely to be subjective/opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not create a specific `FourNumberAdder` if it is not really neccessary. Instead I would use a builder pattern where a `NumberAdder` is created by using a `NumbersBuilder`. This builder could be a `FourNumbersBuilder`, `TenNumbersBuilder` or even a `ThousendNumbersBuilder`. And instead of a getter for each number I would create an `Indexer`, which returns the number at a specific position.

After all I think that it is not possible to give a general solution for your answer because like mentioned before it depends on the use case.

Because if my explanation above I would suggest to take example number #3 it is similar to the builder pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is *very* hypothetical and doesn't make much sense. Design decisions should be driven by use cases though. This helps to make your architecture express those use cases and not some technical details.

Hence it cannot easily be said that option #1, #2, or #3 is the best, because there are no real use cases for your code. No sane developer would program a `FourNumberAdder`.

That being said, I think option #3 makes the most sense, because it correctly bundles up parameters that belong together.